# Spark structured streaming on GCP Dataproc: Trigger not respecting specified interval

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I have set up an environment on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using Dataproc on a Compute Engine cluster with a single node (1 master, 0 workers). My code, present in a file named "transform.py", creates a structured streaming job reading from Pub/Sub and processing the data.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant parts of my code:

```
class Transform:
    def __init__(self, app_name):
        self.app_name = app_name

    def create_spark_session(self):
        spark_session = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .appName(self.app_name)\
            .master("yarn")\
            .getOrCreate()
        return spark_session

    @staticmethod
    def read_stream_from_pubsub(spark_session, project_number, region, subscription) -> DataFrame:
        df = (
            spark_session
            .readStream
            .format("pubsublite")
            .option(
                "pubsublite.subscription",
                f"projects/{project_number}/locations/{region}/subscriptions/{subscription}",
            )
            .load()
        )
        return df

    @staticmethod
    def process_df(df) -> DataFrame:
        ticker_schema = Schemas.ticker_schema()
        ticker_df = df \
            .select(
                f.from_json(f.col('data').cast('string'), ticker_schema).alias('data')
            )
        return ticker_df

    @staticmethod
    def process_df_cast(df_process) -> DataFrame:
        df_process_cast = df_process \
            .select(
                'data.*'
            ) \
            .withColumn('time', f.to_timestamp(f.col('time'))) \
            .withColumn('string_real_time', f.col('time')[0:19]) \
            .withColumn('price_now', f.col('price_now').cast('double')) \
            .withColumn('open', f.col('open').cast('double')) \
            .withColumn('close', f.col('close').cast('double'))

        df_process_cast_group_by_window = df_process_cast \
            .groupBy(
                f.window(f.col('time'), '30 seconds').alias('ventana'),
                f.col('localSymbol'),
                f.col('close'),
                f.col('open')
            ) \
            .agg(
                f.max(f.col('price_now')).alias('max_price_window'),
                f.min(f.col('price_now')).alias('min_price_window'),
                f.first(f.col('price_now')).alias('start_price_window'),
                f.last(f.col('price_now')).alias('end_price_window'),
            )

        df_process_cast_group_by_window = df_process_cast_group_by_window\
            .select(
                f.col('*')
            ) \
            .withColumn('start_window', f.col('ventana.start')) \
            .withColumn('end_window', f.col('ventana.end'))

        return df_process_cast_group_by_window

    def main(self):
        ss = self.create_spark_session()
        df = self.read_stream_from_pubsub(ss, settings.PROJECT_NUMBER, settings.REGION, settings.SUBSCRIPTION)
        ticker_df = self.process_df(df)
        ticker_df_cast = self.process_df_cast(ticker_df)

        query = ticker_df_cast.writeStream \
            .foreachBatch(self.analysis_batch) \
            .outputMode('update') \
            .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds') \
            .start()
        query.awaitTermination()

    def analysis_batch(self, ticker_df_cast, epoch_id):
        print("im here")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    transform = Transform("APP_IB_SCALPING")
    transform.main()
```

My issue is that even though I have set the trigger to 30 seconds, my job seems to be running every 90 seconds. It appears that the specified trigger interval is not being respected.

Is there any configuration that I might be missing or any reasons why this might be happening?

What I've tried:

I double-checked my code to ensure the processingTime for the trigger is indeed set to '30 seconds'.
I inspected the Dataproc cluster metrics to see if there's any unusual spike in resource usage that might delay the processing, but everything seems normal.
I also verified the source Pub/Sub topic to see if there was any delay in the messages themselves. It seems the messages are being published as expected.
I reviewed the Spark logs to check for any potential error messages or warnings, but there were none indicating issues with the timing.
What I was expecting:

Given that I set the trigger to '30 seconds', I was expecting the structured streaming job to execute every 30 seconds. However, it consistently runs every 90 seconds, which is thrice the specified time. I'm trying to understand why there's this delay and how I can ensure the job respects the trigger time.

As a comment, I'm using this code to upload it to GCP:

```
...
@staticmethod
def submit_job(project_id, region, cluster_name, gcs_bucket, spark_filename):
    # Create the job client.
    job_client = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient(
        client_options={"api_endpoint": "{}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443".format(region)}
    )

    # Create the job config.
    job = {
        "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
        "pyspark_job": {
            "main_python_file_uri": "gs://{}/{}".format(gcs_bucket, spark_filename),
            "jar_file_uris": [
                "gs://spark-lib/pubsublite/pubsublite-spark-sql-streaming-LATEST-with-dependencies.jar",
                "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/redislabs/spark-redis_2.11/2.4.2/spark-redis_2.11-2.4.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
            ],
            "python_file_uris": [
                "gs://testing-tmp/proj_BOLSA/"
            ]
        },
    }

    operation = job_client.submit_job_as_operation(
        request={"project_id": project_id, "region": region, "job": job}
    )
    response = operation.result()

    # Dataproc job output is saved to the Cloud Storage bucket
    # allocated to the job. Use regex to obtain the bucket and blob info.
    matches = re.match("gs://(.*?)/(.*)", response.driver_output_resource_uri)

    output = (
        storage.Client()
        .get_bucket(matches.group(1))
        .blob(f"{matches.group(2)}.000000000")
        .download_as_string()
    )

    print(f"Job finished successfully: {output}\r\n")

@staticmethod
def upload_main_file(project, bucket_name, file_name_destination, path_pyspark_file):
    """Uploads the PySpark main file in this directory to the configured input
    bucket."""
    print("Uploading job in pyspark file to Cloud Storage.")
    client = storage.Client(project=project)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name_destination)
    with open(path_pyspark_file, 'rb') as file:
        blob.upload_from_file(file)
    print("Uploaded job pyspark file to Cloud Storage.")

@staticmethod
def upload_folder_structures(project, bucket_name, local_path):
    print("Uploading folder structures to Cloud Storage.")
    rel_paths = glob.glob(local_path + '/**', recursive=True)
    client = storage.Client(project=project)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    for local_file in rel_paths:
        remote_path = f'{"/".join(local_file.split(os.sep)[settings.NUM_FOLDER:])}'
        if os.path.isfile(local_file):
            blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
            blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
    print("Uploaded folder structures to Cloud Storage.")
.....

    def main(self):
        DataProc.upload_main_file(self.project_id, self.bucket_name, self.name_file_transform, self.path_file_transform)
        DataProc.upload_folder_structures(self.project_id, self.bucket_name, self.local_path)
        DataProc.submit_job(self.project_id, self.region, self.cluster_name, self.bucket_name, self.name_file_transform)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executeTransform = ExecuteTransform(settings.PROJECT_ID, settings.PROJECT_NUMBER, settings.REGION, settings.ZONE,
                                        settings.RESERVATION, settings.TOPIC, settings.SUBSCRIPTION, settings.REGIONAL,
                                        settings.CLUSTER_NAME, settings.BUCKET_NAME, settings.NAME_FILE_TRANSFORM,
                                        settings.PATH_FILE_TRANSFORM, settings.LOCAL_PATH, settings.NUM_FOLDER)
    executeTransform.main()
```

Comment: Is it because your data writing take more than 30 seconds? Could you also provide a snapshot of your streaming query statistics? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html#structured-streaming-tab

Comment: It would seem strange to me, since it always takes 90 seconds to write the batch, what's more, if I don't write the trigger line of code, it keeps writing me every 90 seconds, which should be written as soon as possible.